# $\frac{\sin3x + 2}{\sin x+2} = 2023^{\sin x-\sin3x}$

Tags: trigonometry, exponentiation, inverse-trigonometric-functions

**The statement of the problem :** Solve in $\mathbb R$ the following equation : $$\frac{\sin3x + 2}{\sin x+2} = 2023^{\sin x-\sin3x}$$

**My approach :** To simplify, we will use the fact that $\sin3x = 3*\sin x -4*\sin^3 x$ . So, if we make the notation $t=\sin x$ , where $t \in [ -1 , 1 ]$ we get the following : $$\frac{-4t^3+3t+2}{t+2} = 2023^{4t^3 - 2t}$$
Now I tried for some time to find some solutions and below you can see a graph, but it seems to me that it is getting super complicated, I managed to find some solutions, but it is difficult for me to prove that they are the only ones.[image: those three are the solutions of the equation]

If possible, I would prefer a solution that provides the use of inequalities or convexity/concavity or inverse trigonometric functions rather than the use of limits or derivatives because I have to present it to a group of students who have not yet learned about these. The problem is from an old textbook and it is before the lesson on limits and derivatives, so there is probably another solution that don't implies them which I'm looking forward to.

All proofs will be helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Formula" $\sin3x = 4*\sin x -3*\sin^3 x$ gives $-1=1$ when $x=\pi/2$...

Comment: Consider three situations: $\sin{(3x)} > \sin{(x)}$;  $\sin{(3x)} < \sin{(x)}$;  $\sin{(3x)} = \sin{(x)}$. Two of them will lead to one side of the equation being greater than 1 and the other side less than 1.

Comment: @CatalinZara thanks for the suggestion , I will try it and I will come with an update!

Comment: @JeanMarie I think it's a misunderstanding the formula comes from $sin(3x)=sin(x+2x)=sin(x)*cos(2x)+cos(x)*sin(2x)=sin(x)*[1-2sin²(x)]+cos(x)*2*cos(x)*sin(x)=sin(x)-2sin³(x)+2cos²(x)*sin(x)=sin(x)-2sin³(x)+2[1-sin²(x)]*sin(x)=sin(x)-2sin³(x)+2sin(x)-2sin³(x)=3sin(x)-4sin³(x). $

Comment: Your derivation is right : but what you obtain ; $3 \sin(x)-4 \sin^3(x)$ is the **opposite** of the right hand side of your formula !

Comment: Now I edited, it was a mistake I made in a hurry, I still put it correctly afterwards.

Comment: Please stop cheating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is my proof:**
We have that $$\frac{\sin(3x)+2}{\sin(x)+2}=2023^{\sin(x)-\sin(3x)}$$
So $$2023^{\sin(3x)}(\sin(3x)+2)=2023^{\sin(x)}(\sin(x)+2)$$
we consider three cases:

$\bullet$If: $\sin(3x)>\sin(x)$

We can deduce that $2023^{\sin(3x)}>2023^{\sin(3x)}>0$ and $\sin(3x)+2>\sin(x)+2>0$

Then $$2023^{\sin(3x)}(\sin(3x)+2)>2023^{\sin(x)}(\sin(x)+2)$$
$\bullet$If: $\sin(3x)<\sin(x)$

We have the same absurd *(by symmetry)*

$\bullet$If: $\sin(3x)=\sin(x)$

The only solutions are verifying $3x=x+2k\pi$ or $3x=\pi-x+2k\pi$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

And finally $x=k\pi$ or $x=\frac{\pi}{4}+k\frac{\pi}{2}$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

**In conclusion:**

$$\mathbb{S}=\{k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}\}\cup\{\frac{\pi}{4}+k\frac{\pi}{2},k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! Below I put an alternative solution in which we prove that $\sin x = \sin3x$ from the injectivity of a function. Can you please tell me if it is correct?

Comment: No problem. The alternative solution is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution to prove that $sinx = sin3x$ . We will write the equation like this $$2023^{\sin(3x)}(\sin(3x)+2)=2023^{\sin(x)}(\sin(x)+2)$$ The function $y +2$ is strictly increasing and $2023^{y}$ is strictly increasing too $\implies$ the function $f:\mathbb R  \rightarrow \mathbb R$, $f(x)=2023^y( y + 2)$ is strictly increasing , so it's injective.

Returning to the initial equation we have the fact that $f(\sin3x)=f(\sin x) \implies \sin 3x = \sin x$ from the injectivity of the function.